# Roaming between Access Points, incorrect routing?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, routing, wireless-access-point

## **Network setup**

My current network setup is as follows, a **Main Router** followed by a series of two **Access Points**:

`Router <---> AP1 <---> AP2`

The two access points are routers wired via Ethernet cables and configured in AP mode, all the SSIDs are different (I want to be able to pick manually which one to use).

## **The problem**

An **IP Camera** is connected to the network via AP2 on 192.168.1.200 (enforced by a DHCP rule on the main router based on the MAC address), I'm also connected with my **laptop** to the network via AP2. Everything works fine, I can access my camera on 192.168.1.200.

The problem is that if I switch from AP2 to the Main Router I can't access my camera anymore, pinging 192.168.1.200 simply fails. The **other devices** that were already connected to the Main Router are still able to reach the camera.

It is like AP2 thinks I'm still connected there and doesn't forward the traffic through AP1 and then the Main Router.

## **Question**

What could be causing this? Do I have to search the problem also on my laptop configuration (linux) or only in the network? Which are the possible solutions?

---

## **Edit** (additional network info)

**Main Router:** Asus N55U

```
IP: 192.168.1.1
Mask: 255.255.255.0
DHCP enabled with the following manual rules:
- AP1 on 192.168.1.2
- AP2 on 192.168.1.3
- IP Camera on 192.168.1.200
```

**AP1:** Xiaomi MINI Router

```
IP: 192.168.1.2
Mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.1.1
Mode: Access Point
Custom Firmware: Padavan (Asus)
```

**AP2:** Xiaomi NANO Router

```
IP: 192.168.1.3
Mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.1.1 (is this correct?)
Mode: Access Point
Custom Firmware: Padavan (Asus)
```

I did also try to replace **AP2** with a Belkin router in AP mode and had the same result. I did the same test from my phone too:

- Connected to Main Router: Can access IPCam
- Switch to AP2: Can access IPCam
- Back to Main Router: **Can't** access IPCam

Comment: How are they physically connected?  Since they all seem to be routers, have you disabled DHCP on each router, and are all they all interconnected  to each other via the **LAN** interfaces?

Comment: @Zoredache Yes, the AP mode of the routers automatically disables DHCP. The connections - starting from the Main Router, `-->` representing a cable, `(...)` a device - are as follows: `(LAN) --> (WAN, LAN) --> (WAN)`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Well, I don't know that hardware specifically, but usually with most other devices you would connect all the LAN interfaces, and leave the WAN interfaces disconnected.

Comment: @Zoredache Thank you, you are right, this fixed my problem. You had the right intuition in detecting there was something wrong there. If you want to write it out as an answer I will accept it. The only time I had to wire more routers together I had to create separate networks sharing only the internet access, so I guess in that case it was ok to wire `LAN --> WAN`?